# Redirect if authenticated logic in Laravel's built-in auth?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1

This question has been asked before, and I believe my code to be correct, but I am getting strange behaviour.

I need to redirect the user to different routes after login depending on some database values.  I thought that in order to do this I simply had to place my logic in the `handle` method of `app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php`.  My method currently looks like so:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if ($this->auth->check()) {
        if($this->auth->user()->sign_up_complete == 1){
            return redirect('/');
        } else {
            if($this->auth->user()->step_one_complete == 0){
                return redirect('/register/step-1');
            } elseif($this->auth->user()->step_two_complete == 0){
                return redirect('/register/step-2');
            } else {
                return redirect('/');
            }
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

This does not work, and upon login the user is redirected to `/home`.  I have tried placing `dd($this->auth->user())` inside the `$this->auth->check()` condition, but it never gets run.  If I place it outside of that check then it's run on every request.  It looks like `$this->auth->check()` is never run.

My question: If not here, where should this logic go?

I have removed `protected $redirectTo = '/account';` from the `AuthController.php` controller too.

Comment: And where is that `check()` function

Comment: `RedirectIfAuthenticated` seems a `guest` middleware. Also in `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RedirectUsers` if you not set the `$redirectTo`, will be redirected to `/home`. But it doesn't matter in this case. Have you tried the `Authenticate` middleware instead? Move your logic after the `$this->auth->guest()` check, what your wrote. This middleware will run everytime if the user need to be authenticated. So the basic check will redirect them if not authenticated. If it, it will continue to your check.

Comment: @Iamzozo I'm not sure I follow.  That seems to be for something else entirely?

Comment: It seems. If I'm using `guest` middleware, it run `RedirectIfAuthenticated`. But `auth` middleware not run `RedirectIfAuthenticated`, but runs `Authenticate`. Because you want to check the user after login, if he completed all steps, all protected page with `auth` will run `Authenticate` middleware, so run your check. `guest` middleware used if you want to redirect your users from pages what not needed. For example, if the user logged in, you don't want show loginform. Here you use `guest` middleware, what will call `RedirectIfAuthenticated` and redirect to home if he is already logged in.

Comment: @mikemike did you write code for `middleware` in your controller?

Comment: Did you find a fitting answer? Please accept it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not using the middleware correctly. This piece of code will fire everytime you send a request when you are logged in.

To change the redirect location after login you can override the `redirectPath()` method in your AuthController. (You can find the original method in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RedirectsUsers.php`)

This would look something like this:

```
...

public class AuthController extends Controller {

    ...

    public function redirectPath()
    {
        if(Auth::user()->sign_up_complete == 1) {
            return '/';
        } else {
            if(Auth::user()->step_one_complete == 0) {
                return '/register/step-1';
            } elseif(Auth::user()->step_two_complete == 0) {
                return '/register/step-2';
            } else {
                return '/';
            }
        }
    }


    // The rest of the class implementation.

}
```

*Note: I've replaced the `$this->auth()` method with the Facade alternative (`Auth::`). Just because I am not sure if the AuthController has an `auth()` method.*

Answer (score 12):

High level answer: the purpose of `RedirectIfAuthenticated` is to keep an already authenticated user from reaching the login or registration routes/views since they're already logged in.

Test: bookmark the login view. Then login. Close the browser or window. Open the login bookmark. You'll go straight to user's home or where ever specified in `RedirectIfAuthenticated`.

For purposes of the LoginController, create a `redirecTo()` method, which is what the `redirectPath()` method looks for to see if you have customized the redirect.

```
// example
public function redirectTo()
{
    switch (auth()->user()->role) {
        case 'foo':
            return route('foo.home');

        case 'bar':
            return route('bar.home');

        default:
            auth()->logout();
            return route('web.welcome');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To understand why your routing logic is never reached, you should look in `app/Http/Kernel.php` where the RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware is registered:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    ...
];
```

This means if a user navigates to a route that is not protected by the `guest` route middleware, the request never passes through the RedirectIfAuthenticated class and so misses your logic completely.

You can add guest middleware to your registration routes in your routes file to force the routing to pass through your code like this:

```
Route::get('/register/step-1', '<YOUR CONTROLLER METHOD>')->middleware('guest');
```

But, since you say the user is already logged in (not a guest) you should instead move your code as suggested by the other answers.

Only adding this as an answer, because it couldn't be clarified in the space allowed by a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Solution is in Mark Walet's answer, but need little correction. Return should be a string:

```
public class AuthController extends Controller {

    ...

    public function redirectPath()
    {
        if(Auth::user()->sign_up_complete == 1) {
            return '/';
        } else {
            if(Auth::user()->step_one_complete == 0) {
                return '/register/step-1';
            } elseif(Auth::user()->step_two_complete == 0) {
                return '/register/step-2';
            } else {
                return '/';
            }
        }
    }


    // The rest of the class implementation.

}
```

Comment: This should be something you say in a comment in my solution. Then I got a notification and updated it right away.

Comment: oh.. ok, sorry. Will do like this next time

Answer (score 2):

I think it's so easy as setting up a custom Middleware class to validate your requests based on the database values, I do this for excluding users without the correct role.

The role is defined in my user table and only users with the administrator role are allowed to access the system.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;

class RolesMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // If a user is authenticated
        if(\Auth::user() != null)
        {
            // If the user doesn't have the correct role
            if(\Auth::user()->role != 'administrator')
            {
                // logout the user
                \Auth::logout();

                // create a new MessageBag
                $messageBag = new MessageBag;

                // add a message
                $messageBag->add('not_allowed', 'You are not allowed to login, because you do not have the right role!');

                // redirect back to the previous page with errors
                return \Redirect::to('login')->withErrors($messageBag);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

u cant change the core files of laravel all u need to do is adding this code to 
Auth\AuthController

```
protected $redirectPath = '/dashboard';
```